# What is the default value for Boolean Out variable in PL/SQL Procedures?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there any default value for the Boolean Out variable in oracle procedures? Do we need to assign any default value?

Comment: if you don't supply  a value it will be null, as is true for other data types.  nothing special about boolean

Comment: Thank you !! @OldProgrammer. Cleared my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for any variable of any data type that has not had a value assigned is `NULL`; this is the same for `OUT` parameters (which are effectively just another variable you can assign a value to).

`BOOLEAN` data types are no exception as they can have three possible states:

- `TRUE`
- `FALSE`
- `NULL`

For example this shows the values of an unassigned `BOOLEAN` (and then the values after it has been assigned values):

```sql
DECLARE
  value BOOLEAN;

  PROCEDURE print_boolean( message VARCHAR2, value BOOLEAN )
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( message );
    IF value = TRUE THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'True' );
    ELSIF value = FALSE THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'False' );
    ELSIF value IS NULL THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Null' );
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Something Else' );
    END IF;
  END;
BEGIN
  print_boolean( 'DEFAULT: ', value );
  value := TRUE;
  print_boolean( 'TRUE:    ', value );
  value := FALSE;
  print_boolean( 'FALSE:   ', value );
  value := NULL;
  print_boolean( 'NULL:    ', value );
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> DEFAULT: Null
> TRUE:    True
> FALSE:   False
> NULL:    Null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0226c3d263a810315a00fcd452c9555)*